# Pygame picture change through a key not working?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make an easteregg for my friend in a test game for pygame I am making and sadly when I have tried to switch the main picture image it will not switch though no errors resolve! Here is the code:

```
carImg = pygame.image.load("ship.png")
```

That's the image variable

```
            elif event.key == pygame.K_c:
                carImg = pygame.image.load("ee.png")
                car(x,y)
                pygame.display.update()
                gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))
```

That's the easteregg bind,

Problem: Picture variable won't change

Tried: To switch via the 'c' key as shown above

Errors: None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to:

```
global carImg
carImg = pygame.image.load("ee.png")
```

Global variables: [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed something so simple haha, I'll vote as top answer when the timer that stops you from voting so soon runs out.